# I don't have a monitor; how to play copy-protected content?

Tags: hdmi, accessibility, drm

Let me preface this with the fact that I am totally blind so do not have a monitor hooked up to my computer.

I have a cable card tuner that I would like to use to record and play TV shows. It appears that I can record anything I want but cannot play it back if it has the copy protection flag set since I don’t have a monitor hooked up to my computer.

What can I do that will allow me to play back copy-protected content?

Comment: I edited your question to hopefully remove the product recommendation aspects. If you feel my edits changed the intent of your question, feel free to [edit] further, but keep in mind that product recommendation questions are off-topic on SuperUser.

Comment: Sounds like a HDCP problem?

Answer (score 10):

Monitors are pretty cheap, and easy to acquire. If you aren't actually going to be looking at it, a malfunctioning monitor (perhaps with a dead backlight or cracked LCD panel) may be even cheaper.

Comment: But would they be recognised as an HDCP sink and allow you to play the content? It's hard to be sure what exactly is broken and what is still functioning when buying any broken device. Better to just get a very small monitor with HDMI/HDCP support. For example, [this](http://www.amazon.com/HP-VP17-Inch-LCD-Monitor/dp/B000O9UVW4/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1388347893&sr=1-1&keywords=hdcp+monitor) monitor off Amazon, 17 inch, is $40 used and says it supports HDCP. If you buy some other second-hand monitor, make sure it has HDMI/HDCP support.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have HDMI out on your computer? Without knowing the exact issue at hand, you could try getting a device like I bought earlier this year: [Monoprice 108204 Mini HDMI Splitter with 3D Support](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=101&cp_id=10113&cs_id=1011306&p_id=8204&seq=1&format=2). I like to watch my satellite signal remotely over the internet via my Slingbox. This usually entails the TV being off while the satellite box is on, since no one is actually at home watching this. Most channels would come through fine. Pay channels like HBO, Showtime, Starz, etc. would not; those would display an HDCP message along with a blank image. These channels needed the TV to be powered on.

To combat this, I purchased the powered HDMI splitter and it works perfectly. I can tune those pay channels without the TV being on.

It might help in your case as well.